# How can I enable MathJax in chat?

Tags: discussion, faq, mathjax, chat

**Last updated: 9 May 2017**

This is an offshoot of [ChatJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/24293), which enables MathJax along with mhchem on chat.

In order to enable MathJax in chat, please follow the following instructions (courtesy of mhchem's answer below):

> 1. Copy this code into your clipboard

```
    javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var script=document.createElement("script");script.type="text/javascript";script.src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML";var config='MathJax.Ajax.config.path["mhchem"]="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax-mhchem/3.2.0";MathJax.Hub.Config({extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],tex2jax:{inlineMath:[["$","$"],["\\\\\\\\\\\\(","\\\\\\\\\\\\)"]],displayMath:[["$$","$$"],["\\\\[","\\\\]"]],processEscapes:true},TeX:{extensions:["[mhchem]/mhchem.js","cancel.js"]},jax:["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';if(window.opera){script.innerHTML=config}else{script.text=config}document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);window.setInterval(function(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);},1000);}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);}})();
```

> 2. Create a bookmark with this (Chrome: Menu > Bookmarks > Bookmark manager > right click > Add page > ...)
> 3. Whenever you are on a chat page, click the bookmark.

Comment: I'll just add a link to the post [Should chat have TeX support?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support) from meta.math.SE, where several other similar bookmarklets/scripts are linked.

Comment: Does this work on Android?

Answer (score 11):

Update 2017-05-01

The MathJax CDN [retired](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/) and the javascript-URL idea is not so easy any more, because of browser security. (Chrome stips away any leading `javascript:` when pasting into the URL line.  SE modified the `javascript:` link so that it does not work.)

So here is my take. I modified the script to load the **new mhchem (v3)**, together with cancel (and shortened the URL a little bit).

### One-time usage

1. Copy code to clipboard

   ```
   (function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var script=document.createElement("script");script.type="text/javascript";script.src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML";var config='MathJax.Ajax.config.path["mhchem"]="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax-mhchem/3.2.0";MathJax.Hub.Config({extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],tex2jax:{inlineMath:[["$","$"],["\\\\\\\\\\\\(","\\\\\\\\\\\\)"]],displayMath:[["$$","$$"],["\\\\[","\\\\]"]],processEscapes:true},TeX:{extensions:["[mhchem]/mhchem.js","cancel.js"]},jax:["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';if(window.opera){script.innerHTML=config}else{script.text=config}document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);window.setInterval(function(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);},1000);}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);}})();
   ```
2. On chat page, open dev tools (F12 on most browsers)
3. Paste code in console and press ENTER

### Use several times

1. Copy this code into your clipboard

   ```
   javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var script=document.createElement("script");script.type="text/javascript";script.src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML";var config='MathJax.Ajax.config.path["mhchem"]="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax-mhchem/3.2.0";MathJax.Hub.Config({extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],tex2jax:{inlineMath:[["$","$"],["\\\\\\\\\\\\(","\\\\\\\\\\\\)"]],displayMath:[["$$","$$"],["\\\\[","\\\\]"]],processEscapes:true},TeX:{extensions:["[mhchem]/mhchem.js","cancel.js"]},jax:["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';if(window.opera){script.innerHTML=config}else{script.text=config}document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);window.setInterval(function(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);},1000);}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);}})();
   ```
2. Create a bookmark with this (Chrome: Menu > Bookmarks > Bookmark manager > right click > Add page > ...)
3. Whenever you are on a chat page, click the bookmark.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your "one-time usage" snippet, as you've written, but it didn't work in the "Periodic Table" chatroom. I mean to say it did format the mathjax immediately (on pressing Enter), but then on refreshing the page, that formatting disappeared. Is that the intended  behavior or is there a bug? Thanks!

Comment: That is what I would expect. "One-time" means "works just for this page until you go somewhere else or reload".

Comment: Ah, I actually understood it to mean, "use for one time, and then enjoy the results forever" sorry! :P

Comment: Does this work for mobile browsers?

Comment: The 2nd version is a so called "bookmarklet". On some mobile browsers, you cannot even create them. In Chrome on Android, for instance, you cannot create them, but you can use them if you share your bookmarks across devices.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the same principle, this little bookmarklet loads cancel in addition to mhchem:

```
javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var%20script%20=%20document.createElement(%22script%22);script.type%20=%20%22text/javascript%22;script.src%20=%20%22http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML%22;var%20config%20=%20%27MathJax.Hub.Config({%27%20+%20%27extensions:%20[%22tex2jax.js%22],%27%20+%20%27tex2jax:%20{%20inlineMath:%20[[%22$%22,%22$%22],[%22\\\\\\\\\\\\(%22,%22\\\\\\\\\\\\)%22]],%20displayMath:%20[[%22$$%22,%22$$%22],[%22\\\\[%22,%22\\\\]%22]],%20processEscapes:%20true%20},%27%20+%20%27TeX:%20{%20extensions:%20[%22mhchem.js%22,%22cancel.js%22]%20},%27%20+%20%27jax:%20[%22input/TeX%22,%22output/HTML-CSS%22]%27%20+%20%27});%27%20+%20%27MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();%27;if%20(window.opera)%20{script.innerHTML%20=%20config}%20else%20{script.text%20=%20config}%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22head%22)[0].appendChild(script);(doChatJax=function(){window.setTimeout(doChatJax,1000);MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);})();}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);}})();
```

[Start ChatJax with mhchem and cancel](http://javascript:(function()%7Bif(window.MathJax===undefined)%7Bvar%20script%20=%20document.createElement(%22script%22);script.type%20=%20%22text/javascript%22;script.src%20=%20%22http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML%22;var%20config%20=%20%27MathJax.Hub.Config(%7B%27%20%20%20%27extensions:%20[%22tex2jax.js%22],%27%20%20%20%27tex2jax:%20%7B%20inlineMath:%20[[%22$%22,%22$%22],[%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C(%22,%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C)%22]],%20displayMath:%20[[%22$$%22,%22$$%22],[%22%5C%5C%5C%5C[%22,%22%5C%5C%5C%5C]%22]],%20processEscapes:%20true%20%7D,%27%20%20%20%27TeX:%20%7B%20extensions:%20[%22mhchem.js%22,%22cancel.js%22]%20%7D,%27%20%20%20%27jax:%20[%22input/TeX%22,%22output/HTML-CSS%22]%27%20%20%20%27%7D);%27%20%20%20%27MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();%27;if%20(window.opera)%20%7Bscript.innerHTML%20=%20config%7D%20else%20%7Bscript.text%20=%20config%7D%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22head%22)[0].appendChild(script);(doChatJax=function()%7Bwindow.setTimeout(doChatJax,1000);MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);%7D)();%7Delse%7BMathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);%7D%7D)();)

(This also switches to the MathJax distributed network service, http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js)

---

Comment: doesn't work for me for some unknown reason.

Comment: If you have time, it would be helpful to update this to the newest MathJax CDN (this one is sadly dead now), but it's not really urgent, since mhchem has posted a working bookmarklet already.