# Main Chatroom Etiquette Guidelines

Tags: discussion, faq, chat

When I was walking through some of the chatrooms on the network, I found that [mathematics.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3890) has some rules for their chat. I thought this might be a good idea for us as well, hence I propose these guidelines:

1. **Have fun!** Our chatroom is intended for casual conversations. There is almost nothing off-topic there. It's nice of you to drop by and say hello. Please take a moment to see if there is an ongoing discussion, maybe read the transcript for a while, and then weigh in.
2. **[Be nice!](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)** What applies to the main pages does of course apply to the chat.
3. Pinging people in chat is awesome and you can ensure that the target people get the message. But nobody wants to hear the constant "donk" noise all the time. Use it when necessary, but try not to use it any instance possible.
4. You can use MathJax in chat if you want to. You can follow the instructions on [chemistry-meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/89/4945) or on [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220976/) to enable it. Please consider, that not everyone has it up and running, and not everyone wants to have it. Sometimes some users might not be able to contribute to the discussion, especially if it gets very specific. In doubt, see 1. If you want to engage into a deep chemical conversation, consider creating a new chat room dedicated to the subject of your question.
5. The chat is all about fun for everyone, we have members from all around the world and everybody should be able to understand what is being said. That's the reason, why we use English as the main language. With that, of course, we mean the [English language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) and not some sort of internet mash up, like [1337 spik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet). Which can be fun, admittedly, but not everybody understands it.
6. Posting links is fine and talking about them also. Videos, jokes, pictures, everything is fair game. If you have a lot to share, as they take up a lot of  precious space, consider using links in the form of this `[title](http://url)`.

Now, please come, and enjoy conversing with the community. (See 1.)