# Is the chat room bot alive?

Tags: support, feature-request, chat

In the [Main Chatroom Guidelines](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/main-chatroom-etiquette-guidelines) page it mentions a "ChemBot" which allows users to give various commands in chat. Is it still working? If not, can it be fixed?

Comment: It hasn't been around for quite a while, neither has its developer; I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: It's pretty much dead. I deleted the post. Can always be undeleted if it's back at some point in time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elevating to comments to the answer field (because I think they’re enough):

> It hasn't been around for quite a while, neither has its developer; I wouldn't get my hopes up. – Martin - マーチン♦ Jun 25 at 9:39

> It's pretty much dead. I deleted the post. Can always be undeleted if it's back at some point in time... – orthocresol♦ Jun 26 at 7:24

In summary: Yeah, it’s gone.